# Jquery how to make "navigator window" (like photoshop) for locating current position of screen

Tags: jquery, position, screen, thumbnails, navigator

You guys, when we work with image in photoshop, we usually **zoom(+)** it. This action makes image size overflow your phisycal sreen size. But "**navigator windows**" can help us, it looks like "**screen thumbnail**". There's a small rectangle (with red border only) in that windows, for locating "**current position**" of screen size.

Is there any jquery library can do that? I google for a day (with key word **jquery thumbnail navigator windows**) but nothing found, whole results return relate to **"navigation, menu"**.

Any suggestion is appreciated! Thanks!